# Odd issue creating cd-esque structure in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cd, chdir

I've written a program whose main thrust is to continually ask the user for data file names and then to graph those files. However, those files exist in various directories, by design. I decided it'd be nice to be able to navigate around in the standard `cd` style, so that the user can enter said directories easily and choose whichever files he/she wants.

I'm newish to python (and am using 2.7 right now), so maybe I've implemented this poorly, but what follows is my code right now:

```
import os

...

userinput = raw_input('What would you like to do: ').lower()
if userinput.startswith('cd '):
    try:
        newdir = userinput.split('cd ')[1]
        os.chdir(newdir)
        print(os.getcwd()+'\n')
    except:
        print('Not a valid directory.\n')
```

This actually works well for my test cases so far (running in a Windows environment, for better or worse), with the only exception being if the user input is something like `cd ...`. As soon as there are any number of periods other than two, no error is thrown (I've done this without the try/except), and the program remains in the current directory (it prints out wherever it already was, rather than going to the `except` portion of the statement).

In the grand scheme of things this isn't a big deal, since it's just protecting against a typo, but I'm just wondering what's going on here. Thanks!

Comment: Windows is probably interpreting the `.` in filenames in some idiosyncratic way (remember that it's the filename/extension separator). On Linux, I get the expected error message. Try `os.path.splitext('...')` to get a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python isn't doing anything wrong, it seems that windows is just [weird about dots](https://superuser.com/questions/479037/windows-directory).

Comment: Why should it? Should `isdir` treat pathnames differently from `getcwd`? (Surely Windows isn't that crazy...)

Comment: @lars - Apparently so.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert more than two dots into a collection of ../ with a regular expression.  Something like:

```
userinput = re.sub('\.\.\.+', lambda x: os.path.join(*['..']*(len(x.group(0))-1)), userinput)
```